# Animate rotation axes independently

Tags: animation

I'm working on a simple walk cycle and I want to have my character looking around the scene. I already have key frames for the x axis rotation of the head so the character's head bobs as he walks, so is there any way for me to key frame just a single axis of the rotation, so the bob could stay in the x axis and I could have his head move in the z axis without the two interfering? If not, how could I achieve this effect? Do I animate the head rotations first then add the bobbing last? Thanks!

Comment: Use keying sets with the channels you need. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html?highlight=key%20sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a keyframe for a single axis, change the value of your axis in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), hover over it, right mouse button click it and select "Insert Single Keyframe".
This will allow you to change the value of a single axis while keeping the other values untouched.